# Redirect Header Location Issue

Tags: apache, http

When I do a GET to my site from command line telnet, and there is a 302 redirect, the location is coming back concatenated with another part of the URL.  The redirect appears to be working though looking at the inspector.

```
telnet www.mysite.com 80

GET http://www.mysite.com/about/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com
Connection: close

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 01 Oct 2013 21:17:26 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.mysite.comhttp://www.mysite.com/about/
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having?

Comment: there is no problem with functionality, but it looks like a potential issue.  look at "Location:"

Comment: What did you specify inside Header("Location:<>");?

Comment: there is no Header("Location"), this is a straight command from telnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A request like:

```
GET http://www.mysite.com/about/ HTTP/1.1
```

Usually indicates that the browser expects the server that it's talking to to *proxy on its behalf* to the server `www.mysite.com`, which also happens to be the same server that you've contacted. It's not just with **GET**, but **POST** and **HEAD** as well can contain a FQDN URL as part of its request.

If not proxy is setup on apache's end, then it'll simply interpret it as a (perhaps malformed) request.

You only want:

```
GET /about/ HTTP/1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the GET command does not take a host, just the uri.  Host is passed as a separate parameter.  When you enter a host with the GET command it concatenates it to the default host.